# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, discord.py

I was making a discord bot. I tried to add economy to my bot using SQLite3 data base. But when I created a column I got an error:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 30, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

And also, here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        xp INT,
        lvl INT,
        server_id INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 30, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})")
                else:
                    pass

        connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code injection bug!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) Consider what happens if `member`'s stringification is `Foo's Bar`. You'll end up executing

```sql
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('Foo's Bar...
                            -- ^ Syntax error
```

I believe

```py
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}")
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 30, 0, 0, 1, {guild.id})")
```

should be

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ?", ( member.id, ))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, 30, 0, 0, 1, ?)",
   ( str(member), member.id, guild.id ) )
```